# 301 redirect with htaccess in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, http-status-code-301

How to change url from
**`www.abc.com/gallery/?album=id`** to **`www.abc.com/album_name`** with htaccess?

Comment: This isn't possible with htaccess, as how would apache know the album_name? Take a look at Settings > Permalinks in the Wordpress dashboard, this might be more what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the temporary solution
to change url `www.abc.com/gallery/?album=id to www.abc.com/album_id`
by changing htaccess

```
RewriteRule gallery/([^/]+)/? /gallery/?album=$1 [L]
```